# All variables not read from data pipeline - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset with 8 variables,when I run dplyr with syntax below, my output dataframe only has the variables I have used in the dplyr code, while I want all variables

```
ShowID<-MyData %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize (count=n()) %>%
  filter(count==min(count))
ShowID
```

So my output will have two variables - ID and Count. How do I get rest of my variables in the new dataframe? Why is this happening, what am I clueless about here?

```
> ncol(ShowID)
[1] 2
> ncol(MyData)
[1] 8

MYDATA
key     ID  v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0-0-70cf97  1   89  20  30  45  55  65
3ad4893b8c  1   4   5   45  45  55  65
0-0-70cf97d7    2   848 20  52  66  56  56
0-0-70cf    2   54  4   846 65  5   5
0-0-793b8c  3   56454   28  6   4   5   65
0-0-70cf98  2   8   4654    30  65  6   21
3ad4893b8c  2   89  66  518 156 16  65
0-0-70cf97d8    3   89  20  161 1   55  45465
0-0-70cf    5   89  79  48  45  55  456
0-0-793b8c  5   89  20  48  545 654 4
0-0-70cf99  6   9   20  30  45  55  65


DESIRED
key     ID  count   v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6
0-0-70cf99  6   1   9   20  30  45  55  65


RESULT FROM CODE
ID  count
6   1
```

Comment: @RonakShah added

Comment: I'm perplexed as to why group_by(id) removes all other variables? Can someone tell me at what step in my code are the variables being removed from the new data frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the base R `ave` method to calculate number of rows in each group (`ID`) and then select those group which has minimum rows.

```
num_rows <- ave(MyData$v1, MyData$ID, FUN = length)
MyData[which(num_rows == min(num_rows)), ]

#          key ID v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
#11 0-0-70cf99  6  9 20 30 45 55 65
```

You could also use `which.min` in this case to avoid one step however, in case of multiple minimum values it would fail hence, I have used `which`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to summarize:

```
ShowID <- MyData %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(count == min(count))
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm perplexed as to why group_by(id) removes all other variables? we have to end up ungroup() in this code. Can you tell me at what in my code or your code are the variables being removed from the new data frame?

Comment: In my code you aren't removing any variables at any point, only adding one and filtering it.  Your question is about filtering, not summarizing.  When you `summarize`, you need to explicitly tell `dplyr` what you want to summarize.  E.g., It you wanted to find the average of each "`v`" variable, you would need to include `summarize(v1 = mean(v1), v2 = mean(v2))`, etc.  For shortcuts to this, check out `summarize_all`, `summarize_at`, and `summarize_if`.

Comment: In your code you only get two columns after you summarize because you defined a grouping variable `group_by(id)`, and one new variable in your `summarize` call, `count = n()`.  It won't create a summary of any other variable because you didn't tell it to.